# How use EditText inside ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have a listView with adapter in a menu restoran app. I get data from ajax and create a list view with editText for comments and ordered quantity. The problem is when i try to put text in the EditText, the text is erased. I dont know if the list is created again every time y push anything,
This is the code.

fragment:

```
private SopasViewModel sopasViewModel;

    ListView itemsMenu;

    String url="http://192.168.0.15/meseroapp/cargarMenu.php";

    boolean cargado=false;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        sopasViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SopasViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sopas, container, false);

        Log.i("Llamada al onCreate", "entra");
        itemsMenu=(ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.listaSopas);
        Menu m=new Menu();
        m.cargarMenu(url,getActivity(),itemsMenu, "sopas");

        return root;
    }
```

**Menu Class**

```
public class Menu {

    public ArrayList<Plato> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    FragmentActivity activity;

    public Menu() {

    }

    public void cargarMenu(String URL, FragmentActivity activity, ListView itemsMenu, String categoria){
        this.activity=activity;
        Log.i("URL:", URL);
        RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);
       StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try{
                    JSONArray menuJsonArray= new JSONArray(response);
                    cargarLista(menuJsonArray, itemsMenu, categoria);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("JsonArray", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("response: ", error.toString());
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void cargarLista (JSONArray array, ListView itemsMenu, String cat){
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            for(int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonobject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String idString       = jsonobject.getString("id");
                String imagenString   =jsonobject.getString("imagen");
                String nombre    = jsonobject.getString("nombre");
                String descripcion  = jsonobject.getString("descripcion");
                String categoria = jsonobject.getString("categoria");
                String estadoString = jsonobject.getString("estado");
                String precioString =jsonobject.getString("precio");

                int id=Integer.parseInt(idString);
                double precio = Double.parseDouble(precioString);
                int es= Integer.parseInt(estadoString);
                boolean estado;
                if (es==1) { estado=true;}
                else {estado=false;}
                imagenString=imagenString.replace("\\","");

                if (categoria.equals(cat)){
                    if (estado){
                        Plato p=new Plato(id,imagenString,nombre,descripcion,precio,categoria,estado);
                        arrayList.add(p);
                    }
                }

            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e("errorr",e.toString());
        }
        //Log.i("aaaaaaaaa",arrayList.get(0).getNombre());
        SopasAdapter sopasAdaptaer=new SopasAdapter(activity,R.layout.lista_menus, arrayList);
        itemsMenu.setAdapter(sopasAdaptaer);

    }
}
```

**Adapter **

```
public class SopasAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <Plato>{
    private Context mContext;
    private int mResource;

    public SopasAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Plato> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext=context;
        this.mResource=resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(mResource,parent,false);

        ImageView imageView=convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
        TextView txtName=convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemNombre);
        TextView txtDescripcion=convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemDescripcion);
        TextView txtPrecio=convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemPrecio);
        EditText editTxtComentario=convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemComentario);



        CargaImagenes imagen=new CargaImagenes(imageView);
        imagen.execute(getItem(position).getImage());
        txtName.setText(getItem(position).getNombre());
        txtDescripcion.setText(getItem(position).getDescripcion());
        txtPrecio.setText(" "+getItem(position).getPrecio());
        editTxtComentario.setText("Observaciones: ");



        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: text is  erase when?

Comment: when i drop the editText